# Find $(a_1-\frac{1}{a_1})+(a_2-\frac{1}{a_2})+⋯+(a_5-\frac{1}{a_5})$ if $a_i$'s are eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Please help to reach answer for the following problem:

> $A∈M_5(R)$ is a matrix and in relation to $A^2-4A-I=0$. if
>   $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ is eigenvalues for *A*; solve the following
>   problem:
>
> $(a_1-\frac{1}{a_1})+(a_2-\frac{1}{a_2})+⋯+(a_5-\frac{1}{a5})$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you know about the sum the the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: Nice starting point@amd but I was thinking about how to deal with the reciprocal sums of eigenvalues?

Comment: On second, thought the trace is irrelevant. The possible eigenvalues of $A$ have a nice property w/r their inverses.

Comment: @BAYMAX No doubt all of the people asking the question are working from the same material.

Answer (score 3):

$$(a_1-\frac{1}{a_1})+(a_2-\frac{1}{a_2})+⋯+(a_5-\frac{1}{a_5}) = tr{(A-A^{-1})}$$

$$A^2-4A-I = 0 \Rightarrow A(A-4I)= I \Rightarrow A^{-1}=A-4I \Rightarrow A-A^{-1} = A-(A-4I) = 4I$$

$$tr(A-A^{-1}) = 4\cdot 5 = 20$$

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^2-4x-1$ annihilates the matrix $A$ so $$\sigma(A) \subseteq \{\text{ zeros of } x^2-4x-1\} = \{2-\sqrt5, 2+\sqrt5\}$$

Assume that $2-\sqrt{5}$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ with mulyiplicity $k \ge 0$ and $2+\sqrt5$ is the eigenvalue with multiplicity $5-k$.

Then we have

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^5 \left(a_i - \frac1{a_i}\right) &= k\underbrace{\left(2-\sqrt{5} - \frac1{2-\sqrt{5}}\right)}_{=4} + (5-k)\underbrace{\left(2+\sqrt{5} - \frac1{2+\sqrt{5}}\right)}_{=4} \\
&= 4k + 4(5-k) \\
&= 4\cdot 5 \\
&= 20
\end{align}

We see that the result is independent of $k$.